# Can we hide background labels?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, labeling

I've got a layer with all the states of the country, and layer with 1 states regions.  When enabling the labels I don't want the states region to be displayed for the state where the regions are displayed.

Is there anyway to hide a label if another is on top of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the label weight for the regions to be higher than that of the states:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/weighting-labels-and-features.htm

Comment: Looks like Ive omited a detail, Im working with poligons, so even if I change theyr weight the label with a lower rank will still be desplayed if it has enought space.
(or I might be blind or something)
Thank you for your time .

Comment: Or maby Im looking at this the wrong way, and try should try with Label expresion and somehow tell the second Layer to show labels only for the polygons where they have overlaping boundrys with the first Layer